# How to open text message with URL preview?

Tags: html, sms

All.

I just have code in my .php file like for text message preview

```
<a href="sms:1234567890?body=https://www.youtube.com/ Test" style="color:blue;background-color:#FFA500">Test</a>
```

if we are going click on Test from mobile then you can see message preview in message box In that i want saw URL Preview with thumbnail same like whatsapp (thumbnail with URL)

e.g. https://www.labsmobile.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/campaign_example.jpg

What i need to add for that can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in Advance

Have tried Meta property for that

Comment: What makes you think that was _possible_ for SMS?

Comment: Based on few research i just checked and may be its possible.

https://fixyourfunnel.com/blog/link-previews-for-text-messages
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2444/_index.html
https://www.emergeinteractive.com/insights/detail/rich-video-previews-in-ios-macos-messages/
https://simpletexting.com/sms-link-previews/